# How to seed data with AddOrUpdate with a complex key in EF 4.3

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4.3, seed, linq-expressions, entity-framework-migrations

I am trying to seed a development database with some test data.

I have used `context.People.AddOrUpdate(p => p.Id, people));` with much success.

I have another table that I need to seed, in which I would not know the primary key.

For example, I would want to AddOrUpdate based on the First and Last names matching.

I am unsure how to write the Expression correctly.

```
context.People.AddOrUpdate(p => p.FirstName && p.LastName, people);
```

is obviously incorrect, but I hope it conveys the solution I am looking for.

Answer (score 211, accepted):

Try this:

```
context.People.AddOrUpdate(p => new { p.FirstName, p.LastName }, people);
```

Comment: @LadislavMrnka what if the identifier needs to be a complex type i.e. 

`context.People.AddOrUpdate(p => new { p.Name.FirstName, p.Name.LastName }, people)`?

Comment: @LadislavMrnka, also, what if the property is a nullable type? i.e.     `context.People.AddOrUpdate(p => new { p.Birthdate }, people)` ?

Comment: Something to note here is that the 'people' collection needs to be an ARRAY and not a list. If you have a list of entities, you can simply call .ToArray() on the list. I struggled with that one :) - Good answer

Comment: can't get this to work. possibly because (in addition to 3 properties specified in composite key) i have a another ID field with auto generated numbers?

Comment: @LadislavMrnka  is need to keep Migration folder(Configuration.cs and...) after do migration and update database fields???

Comment: @gabe You can use the Id column for your complex type. You can do: `context.Names.AddOrUpdate(n => new { n.FirstName, n.LastName, }, name); context.People.AddOrUpdate(p => new { p.NameId, }, people);`. It will work even if both are newly added to the database assuming the default value C# value of your `Name.Id` property is not a valid value for that column in the database—i.e., if you use the default generated `IDENTITY(1, 1)` and not `IDENTITY(0, 1)` you’ll be fine.

Comment: How to add navigation property of other table foreign key in code first approach? I have structure like `context.People.AddOrUpdate(p => new { p.Name.FirstName, p.Name.LastName }, people) `? It this possible?

Answer (score 1):

If you got `Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.` because of using navigation property - consider adding foreign key property directly to the entity (maybe only with getter) and use it as *Ladislav Mrnka* proposed.

Comment: How to add navigation property of other table foreign key in `code first` approach? 
I have structure like `context.People.AddOrUpdate(p => new { p.Name.FirstName, p.Name.LastName }, people)` ? It this possible

Comment: If I set getter property error is `The specified type member 'NameId' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.`