# C# ASP.NET MVC: Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying my best to learn ASP.NET MVC programming but I've occurred a problem that I can't resolve. I am writing code - first database, I want to populate 3 of my tables via Seed method, there's the models code:

```
//Doctor Table
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;

    namespace Przychodnia.Models.Clinic
    {
        public class Doctor
        {
            public int DoctorID { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Surname { get; set; }

            public string City { get; set; }
            public string PostCode { get; set; }
            public string Adress { get; set; }

            public string Salary { get; set; }

            [StringLength(9, MinimumLength = 9, ErrorMessage = "Phone number must be 9 characters long.")]
            public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

            public string RoomNumber { get; set; }


            public Specialization Specialization { get; set; }
            public List<Appointment> Appointments { get; set; }
            public List<Vacation> Vacations { get; set; }
        }
    }

//Patient Table
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Przychodnia.Models.Clinic
{
    public class Patient
    {
        public int PatientID { get; set; }

        [StringLength(11, MinimumLength = 11, ErrorMessage = "PESEL number must be 11 characters long.")]
        public string PESEL { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }


        public string City { get; set; }
        public string PostCode { get; set; }
        public string Adress { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }

        public string InsuranceNumber { get; set; }

        [StringLength(9, MinimumLength = 9, ErrorMessage = "Phone number must be 9 characters long.")]
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

        public List<Appointment> Appointments { get; set; }

    }
}
//Specialization Table
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Przychodnia.Models.Clinic
{
    public class Specialization
    {
        public int SpecializationID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Now, I have DummyData class, which looks like so:

```
    using Przychodnia.Models.Clinic;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Przychodnia.Data
{
    public class DummyData
    {
        public static List<Specialization> getSpecializations()
        {
            List<Specialization> specializations = new List<Specialization>()
            {
                new Specialization()
                {
                    Name = "Dermatolog"
                },
                new Specialization()
                {
                    Name = "Chirurg"
                },
                 new Specialization()
                {
                    Name = "Laryngolog"
                }
            };
            return specializations;
        }

        public static List<Doctor> getDoctors(ClinicContext context)
        {
            List<Doctor> doctors = new List<Doctor>()
            {
                new Doctor()
                {
                    Name = "Jan",
                    Surname = "Kowalski",
                    City = "Olsztyn",
                    PostCode = "123-123",
                    Adress = "Boeinga 2/14",
                    Salary = "5500",
                    PhoneNumber = "111222333",
                    RoomNumber = "18",
                    Specialization = context.Specializations.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Name == "Chirurg")
                },
                new Doctor()
                {
                    Name = "Aleksy",
                    Surname = "Dimitriv",
                    City = "Warszawa",
                    PostCode = "300-200",
                    Adress = "Dymowskiego 2/14",
                    Salary = "10000",
                    PhoneNumber = "000999888",
                    RoomNumber = "101",
                    Specialization = context.Specializations.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Name == "Dermatolog")
                },
                new Doctor()
                {
                    Name = "Juliusz",
                    Surname = "Petrarka",
                    City = "Kraków",
                    PostCode = "000-123",
                    Adress = "Mickiewicza 2/14",
                    Salary = "8500",
                    PhoneNumber = "333444222",
                    RoomNumber = "01",
                    Specialization = context.Specializations.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Name == "Laryngolog")
                }

            };
            return doctors;
        }

        public static List<Patient> getPatients()
        {
            List<Patient> patients = new List<Patient>()
            {
                new Patient()
                {
                    Name = "Anna",
                    Surname = "Pszczoła",
                    PESEL = "01234567890",
                    City = "Olsztyn",
                    PostCode = "123-123",
                    Adress = "Heweliusza 22",
                    BirthDate = DateTime.Now,
                    InsuranceNumber = "123123123ZZ",
                    PhoneNumber = "123321123"
                },
                new Patient()
                {
                    Name = "Juliusz",
                    Surname = "Słowacki",
                    PESEL = "02030405060",
                    City = "Elbląg",
                    PostCode = "2-123",
                    Adress = "Mariusza 50",
                    BirthDate = DateTime.Now,
                    InsuranceNumber = "00000000123Z",
                    PhoneNumber = "000221122"
                },
                new Patient()
                {
                    Name = "Karolina",
                    Surname = "Ogórek",
                    PESEL = "11104592831",
                    City = "Lublin",
                    PostCode = "123-2",
                    Adress = "Batorego 2",
                    BirthDate = DateTime.Now,
                    InsuranceNumber = "zzxxcc0002333",
                    PhoneNumber = "989231453"
                },

            };
            return patients;
        }
    }
}
```

And I've edited Configuration.cs seed method by adding some lines:

```
        context.Specializations.AddOrUpdate(
        s => s.Name, DummyData.getSpecializations().ToArray());
    context.SaveChanges();

    context.Patients.AddOrUpdate(
        p => new { p.PESEL, p.Name, p.Surname, p.City, p.PostCode, p.Adress, p.BirthDate, p.InsuranceNumber, p.PhoneNumber }, DummyData.getPatients().ToArray());
    context.SaveChanges();

    context.Doctors.AddOrUpdate(
        d => new { d.Name, d.Surname, d.City, d.PostCode, d.Adress, d.Salary, d.PhoneNumber, d.RoomNumber, d.Specialization }, DummyData.getDoctors(context).ToArray());
    context.SaveChanges();
```

Then, when I try to update-database I am getting this kind of message:

```
"Unable to create a constant value of type 'Przychodnia.Models.Clinic.Specialization'. 
Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context."
```

Comment: just a guess but can you not change d.Specialization to d.Specialization.Name? You're passing in an object which is a complex type, whereas name is a primitive type

Comment: Well I want to populate my database with complete objects not just names, I am following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p9GdkmFzoPw and it works perfectly fine in the video, the diffrence is I have more complex database model and I could mess up something, to specify I am currently at 28:30. When I was creating previous project I've done it a little bit in a diffrent way, which was overcomplicated but I remember that I was passing whole objects and they worked nicely.

Comment: Which line of code is throwing the exception?

Answer (score 1):

You can't assign `d.Specialization` directly inside `AddOrUpdate` method since `d.Specialization` itself declared as a complex class, which that method expects all property arguments in expression tree declared as primitive/simple types. Instead, you can create `SpecializationID` unique key property inside `Doctor` class and add proper association for that property to `Specialization` class like this:

```
public class Doctor
{
    // other primitive type properties

    // since EF is used, ForeignKeyAttribute may be used here
    [ForeignKey("Specialization")]
    public int SpecializationID { get; set; }

    public virtual Specialization Specialization { get; set; }
}
```

Then, you need to adjust `AddOrUpdate` method expression by including `SpecializationID` property to replace `Specialization` class:

```
context.Doctors.AddOrUpdate(
        d => new { d.Name, d.Surname, d.City, d.PostCode, d.Adress, d.Salary, d.PhoneNumber, d.RoomNumber, d.SpecializationID }, DummyData.getDoctors(context).ToArray());
```

A similar issue may be found here (with multiple complex classes instead of one):

[`Only primitive types or enumeration are supported in this context` error whilst seeding ASP.NET MVC using AddOrUpdate match on multiple fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42316385/only-primitive-types-or-enumeration-are-supported-in-this-context-error-whilst)

Comment: There is no need to change the code like that, since migration file automatically detect relationship and insert the forein and primary keys in a proper way, I just don't understand why my database is not getting populated by specialization, is there any other way to populate it?

Answer (score 0):

Allright, I got it now! I'll post the answer so maybe it'll help somebody.
All I had to do is to change the seed method like so

```
 context.Specializations.AddOrUpdate(
        s =>  s.SpecializationID , DummyData.getSpecializations().ToArray());
    context.SaveChanges();
    context.Patients.AddOrUpdate(
        p => p.PatientID, DummyData.getPatients().ToArray());
    context.SaveChanges();

    context.Doctors.AddOrUpdate(
        d => d.DoctorID, DummyData.getDoctors(context).ToArray());
    context.SaveChanges();
```

So it pass only primitive type and the rest of populating is done in DummyData.cs , well it was simple as that...